# can someone check whats wrong with my code i been tryna build a gui simple calc

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter

```
from tkinter import *
root=Tk()
root.title("simple calc")



def button_click(number):
    global current
    current=input1.get()
    input1.delete(0,END)
    global number0
    number0=input1.insert(0,str(current)+str(number))

    if number=="+":
        input1.delete(0,END)

def equal():
    input1.insert(str(int(number0+current)))
def clear():
     input1.delete(0,END)

input1=Entry(root,width=35)
input1.grid(row=0,column=0,pady=10,padx=10)
button1=Button(root,text="=",padx=10,pady=25,command=equal)
button1.grid(row=0,column=1)
button2=Button(root,text="+",padx=10,pady=10,command=lambda: button_click("+"))
button2.grid(row=1,column=1)
button3=Button(root,text="clear",padx=10,pady=10,command=clear)
button3.grid(row=1,column=2)
button4=Button(root,text="1",padx=10,pady=10,command=lambda: button_click(1))
button4.grid(row=1,column=3)
button5=Button(root,text="2",padx=10,pady=10,command=lambda: button_click(2))
button5.grid(row=2,column=1)
button6=Button(root,text="3",padx=10,pady=10,command=lambda: button_click(3))
button6.grid(row=2,column=2)
button7=Button(root,text="4",padx=10,pady=10,command=lambda: button_click(4))
button7.grid(row=2,column=3)
button8=Button(root,text="5",padx=10,pady=10,command=lambda: button_click(5))
button8.grid(row=3,column=1)
button9=Button(root,text="6",padx=10,pady=10,command=lambda: button_click(6))
button9.grid(row=3,column=1)
button10=Button(root,text="7",padx=10,pady=10,command=lambda: button_click(7))
button10.grid(row=3,column=2)
button11=Button(root,text="8",padx=10,pady=10,command=lambda: button_click(8))
button11.grid(row=3,column=3)
button12=Button(root,text="9",padx=10,pady=10,command=lambda: button_click(9))
button12.grid(row=4,column=1)
button13=Button(root,text="0",padx=10,pady=10,command=lambda: button_click(0))
button13.grid(row=4,column=2)
root.mainloop()
```

i need someone to check where did i do wrong this is my code ,it shows me this error message:Exception in Tkinter callback

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\noamane\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 1921, in __call__
    return self.func(*args)
  File "C:\Users\noamane\PycharmProjects\pythonProject2\main.py", line 18, in equal
    input1.insert(str(int(number0+current)))
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'NoneType' and 'str'</p>
```

Comment: Here `str(int(number0+current))` you are adding a string value to a `None` value.

Comment: "tkinter.Entry.insert" returns "None".

Comment: Take a look at `number0=input1.insert(0,str(current)+str(number))`. `insert` inserts things, it doesn't return a value. What would you like `number0` to be? If its the sum of current and number, assign that to number0 before the insert.